# How can I activate my iPod if my PC is running Linux?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch

I just bought an iPod, and when I turn it shows an image with the USB cable and iTunes. It wants me to plug it to a computer with iTunes? But I use Linux, what do I do?

Comment: Go back to the Apple Store and ask them to activate the iPod for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few solutions, not all of them good:

- If possible, update to iOS 5 (probably at the Apple Store) and don't use iTunes.
- Find a friend with a Mac or a PC and get them to activate it.
- Go to the Apple Store (as Randolph said) and ask them.
- Run Windows in VirtualBox (or another VM solution), and use iTunes from there. (thanks, Fake Name)
- Get sixty million of your best friends to switch to Linux and all complain at Apple for a Linux port of iTunes.
- Run iTunes in Wine, if that's possible.

Comment: I don't think it'll run in WINE. Too many dependencies on device drivers I think.

Comment: That's why it's after "get sixty million people to ask for iTunes on Linux" - it's less likely to happen.

Comment: You forgot "Install Windows in a VirtualBox VM, install iTunes, Activate iPod". It's probably easiest.

Comment: I gone back to the store, thanks! Now I'll read about synchronization using Rhythmbox or iTunes with wine.. :)